# #quarkus 3.20 introduced Build Error not in 2.16.x

Tags: quarkus

This 3.2.0 service gets this compile error only when using a homegrown 3.2.0 extension which uses several other home grown 3.2.0 extensions. The problem is there is no indication of which class is the offending class. I have searched all the code of all extensions and there are none tagged @Provider which are not also @ApplicationScoped. Any help figuring out where to find the offender would be greatly appreciated.
The problem did not arise with the same code for 2.16.6.

```
`Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.2.0.Final:build (default) on project edcs-quarkus-sample-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR] [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems:
[ERROR] [1] Ambiguous dependencies for type jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR] - java member: io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyWriter():providers
[ERROR] - declared on CLASS bean [types=[jakarta.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<java.lang.Object>, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.spi.ServerMessageBodyWriter$AllWriteableMessageBodyWriter, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.types.AllWriteableMarker, io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyWriter, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.spi.ServerMessageBodyWriter<java.lang.Object>, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyWriter]
[ERROR] - available beans:
[ERROR] - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.lang.Object, jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers providers(), declaringBean=org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.ContextProducers]
[ERROR] - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.lang.Object, jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers providers(), declaringBean=io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusContextProducers]
[ERROR] [2] Ambiguous dependencies for type jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR] - java member: io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyReader():providers
[ERROR] - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyReader, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.jackson.JacksonBasicMessageBodyReader, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.providers.serialisers.AbstractJsonMessageBodyReader, jakarta.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<java.lang.Object>, org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.spi.ServerMessageBodyReader<java.lang.Object>, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.FullyFeaturedServerJacksonMessageBodyReader]
[ERROR] - available beans:
[ERROR] - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.lang.Object, jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers providers(), declaringBean=org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.ContextProducers]
[ERROR] - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.lang.Object, jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers providers(), declaringBean=io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusContextProducers]`
```

Comment: We'd need to see some code to be able to figure out what's going on

Comment: closed - jandex index version changed to 3.1.2

Comment: if I were you I would add that as an answer. That makes it easy for future readers to see it's the proper solution without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with use of 3.1.2 jandex plugin and removal of a couple of @Provider that weren't necessary.

The jandex index seemed to be the important change.